# Is is possible to install Ubuntu on a computer with no OS

Tags: games, compiling

I'm building a gaming pc. I would like to install Ubuntu as my first OS. But I'm wondering is is possible to install it without having a OS installed, and how would I do this.

Comment: Why buy a computer with a pre-installed OS, if you're not going to use that OS? So to save money you can buy a computer with no OS or just FreeDOS and install Ubuntu on it yourself. The next question that remains after that is if your hardware is compatible with Linux. You should research what filesystem format to use for the Western Digital 3TB hard drive before you install an OS on it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I install Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu)

Comment: We do not care about the details of the PC. Removed it.

Answer (score 0):

As it's a gaming rig, the key questions are "Will my games run under Linux, or do I need Windows?" and "Does Linux support my hardware (especially my graphics card)?" If you need Windows and have only one HDD in your system it's much easier to instal Windows first and then put Ubuntu on afterwards. There is plenty of help and advice about how to do this in the Ubuntu forums and elsewhere on the internet.

If you don't need Windows then go right ahead and instal from DVD or USB stick. This is what I did with my new build, which wasn't a gaming rig. I just went with Ubuntu's suggested options and all went fine.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to install Ubuntu without having an OS installed. First download the Ubuntu ISO you want to install, then you have two options:

1. Burn the ISO to a DVD, then boot from the DVD from BIOS boot menu.
2. Raw copy the ISO to an USB stick, then boot from the USB stick from BIOS boot menu.

For a more detailed description of these installation methods see: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-ubuntu-desktop (thanks @David Foerster)

Comment: You can find more detailed instructions [on the official download page](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/). It would be better to just link to those.

Answer (score 0):

You will need an Ubuntu installation disk.

If you have another computer you can download Ubuntu and burn it to a DVD or an USB. You can do that from any operating system. How you do that from anything other than Ubuntu  I leave up to the reader. Ubuntu has an option called "startup disk creator" so we have it pretty easy.

Problem arise if this is the only system you have. Besides using the computer from someone else (parents, siblings, friends etc.) you can also purchase an [installation DVD](http://shop.canonical.com/index.php?cPath=17). You can buy a single dvd for 5.04 pounds with the 64-bit version. If you want a 32-bit version this is no longer an option (current systems will not be 32-bit).

Installing it is the same as with a system with an operating system in you: you boot from the media it is on and follow the instructions.

What you also need to consider is that Ubuntu is NOT a gaming platform at the moment. Yes we have games and there is a game tool called Steam. But it is very limited in what games you can play. You can forget about playing high end Windows games. Valve will announce an update to the OpenGL driver soon and it looks pretty promising. If you want to play those you will also need to purchase a Windows operating system.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can install Ubuntu. For your "high-end games" install Wine: sudo apt-get install wine. If you're not too savvy with Wine install Playonlinux: sudo apt-get install playonlinux. Works with most Windows based games like World of Warcraft and others. You have to have the installation CDs still. Hope that helps.